# How i can select and show multiples items description in a level field and items id insert into database using Angularjs and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I can select multiple items for example 1,2 and also insert those id's into database. But i want to show selected descriptions in a text level field.

### id | Description

### 1  | item_1

### 2  | item_2

3  | item_3

But i can show id's in text level field cause `ng-model="item_id"` contains array of id show i can bind it in a text field.

here i insert id into database

```
'foreach($req->id as $insert)
    {
        DB::table('item_details')->insert([
        'manf_id'=>$req->manf_id,
        'goods_id'=>$req->goods_id,
        'id'=>$insert


    ]);

    }`
```

here is my code `ng-options="item.id item.id+'-'+item.Description for item in allItems"`

Well id will go into database and Description will show in a text field.

Comment: can you show that how your doing this witha plunker

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show more of the relevant code. From the current description it's not really clear what currently happens or what you want to change. What is a "level field"?

Comment: id will go in to database and Description will show in a text field. @nnnnnn